# Update a document returned by findOne()/find()/findById() - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm wondering that if there's any method available to change the values of available fields of a document object returned by mongoose `find()`,`findOne()` and `findById()` methods and update them with changes applied into the database. Below code snippet is what I'm expecting for to done the job I want:

```
User.findOne({ email: email })
      .then(user => {
        if (user) {
            user.fieldToUpdate = "Updated value"; // Here I'm getting the field and updating it with the new value;
            user.save().then().catch(); // Here I'm updating the document to the database, expecting for a promise object
        } else {
          const error = new Error("No such user in the database.");
          error.httpStatusCode = 422;
          next(error);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        next(error);
      });
```

Comment: [`updateOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateOne)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you wrote will work fine, but if you need to just update the found document:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ email }, { email: 'sample@test.com' })
  .then((err, user) => {
    //
  }
```

[More on the Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

Comment: Thanks! I think using findOneAndUpdate() is more convenient for this purpose.